# How to create scaleThreshold legend in D3 v5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following this tutorial about how to create legends, in particular I need the scaleThreshold:

[how to create legends](https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-legend)

I understand that I can't use import because it works only in Observable's cell, so I have to copy the entire function and code is like that:

```
legend({
  color: d3.scaleThreshold([2.5, 3.1, 3.5, 3.9, 6, 7, 8, 9.5], d3.schemeRdBu[9]),
  title: "Unemployment rate (%)",
  tickSize: 0
})

function legend({
  color,
  title,
  tickSize = 6,
  width = 320, 
  height = 44 + tickSize,
  marginTop = 18,
  marginRight = 0,
  marginBottom = 16 + tickSize,
  marginLeft = 0,
  ticks = width / 64,
  tickFormat,
  tickValues
} = {}) {

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .style("overflow", "visible")
      .style("display", "block");

  let tickAdjust = g => g.selectAll(".tick line").attr("y1", marginTop + marginBottom - height);
  let x;

  // Continuous
  if (color.interpolate) {
    const n = Math.min(color.domain().length, color.range().length);

    x = color.copy().rangeRound(d3.quantize(d3.interpolate(marginLeft, width - marginRight), n));

    svg.append("image")
        .attr("x", marginLeft)
        .attr("y", marginTop)
        .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
        .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
        .attr("xlink:href", ramp(color.copy().domain(d3.quantize(d3.interpolate(0, 1), n))).toDataURL());
  }

  // Sequential
  else if (color.interpolator) {
    x = Object.assign(color.copy()
        .interpolator(d3.interpolateRound(marginLeft, width - marginRight)),
        {range() { return [marginLeft, width - marginRight]; }});

    svg.append("image")
        .attr("x", marginLeft)
        .attr("y", marginTop)
        .attr("width", width - marginLeft - marginRight)
        .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
        .attr("xlink:href", ramp(color.interpolator()).toDataURL());

    // scaleSequentialQuantile doesn’t implement ticks or tickFormat.
    if (!x.ticks) {
      if (tickValues === undefined) {
        const n = Math.round(ticks + 1);
        tickValues = d3.range(n).map(i => d3.quantile(color.domain(), i / (n - 1)));
      }
      if (typeof tickFormat !== "function") {
        tickFormat = d3.format(tickFormat === undefined ? ",f" : tickFormat);
      }
    }
  }

  // Threshold
  else if (color.invertExtent) {
    const thresholds
        = color.thresholds ? color.thresholds() // scaleQuantize
        : color.quantiles ? color.quantiles() // scaleQuantile
        : color.domain(); // scaleThreshold

    const thresholdFormat
        = tickFormat === undefined ? d => d
        : typeof tickFormat === "string" ? d3.format(tickFormat)
        : tickFormat;

    x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-1, color.range().length - 1])
        .rangeRound([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(color.range())
      .join("rect")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i - 1))
        .attr("y", marginTop)
        .attr("width", (d, i) => x(i) - x(i - 1))
        .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
        .attr("fill", d => d);

    tickValues = d3.range(thresholds.length);
    tickFormat = i => thresholdFormat(thresholds[i], i);
  }

  // Ordinal
  else {
    x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(color.domain())
        .rangeRound([marginLeft, width - marginRight]);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(color.domain())
      .join("rect")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", marginTop)
        .attr("width", Math.max(0, x.bandwidth() - 1))
        .attr("height", height - marginTop - marginBottom)
        .attr("fill", color);

    tickAdjust = () => {};
  }

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - marginBottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(ticks, typeof tickFormat === "string" ? tickFormat : undefined)
        .tickFormat(typeof tickFormat === "function" ? tickFormat : undefined)
        .tickSize(tickSize)
        .tickValues(tickValues))
      .call(tickAdjust)
      .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
      .call(g => g.append("text")
        .attr("x", marginLeft)
        .attr("y", marginTop + marginBottom - height - 6)
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text(title));

  return svg.node();
}

function ramp(color, n = 256) {
  const canvas = DOM.canvas(n, 1);
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    context.fillStyle = color(i / (n - 1));
    context.fillRect(i, 0, 1, 1);
  }
  return canvas;
}
```

But I am getting nothing neither errors.

Comment: Hi @stackfac, could you point out what errors you're facing or give more information about it

Comment: Hi @luissevillano that's point, I am not getting any errors, but the legend doesn't appear. If you try to copy and paste the code, the legend shouldn't appear and I don't know why. Thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `legend` function returns a HTML node so you have to *add* it wherever you want it to show.

```js
// you can store the return of the funcion
var legendElement = legend({
    color: d3.scaleThreshold(
        [2.5, 3.1, 3.5, 3.9, 6, 7, 8, 9.5],
        d3.schemeRdBu[9]
    ),
    title: "Unemployment rate (%)",
    tickSize: 0,
});

// and then append to some element
document.querySelector("body").append(legendElement);
```